# flutter version management global mode doesn't work

Tags: flutter

I'm working with flutter versions management([fvm](https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm)).
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Run fvm.bat use 1.24.0-10.2.
2. Run fvm.bat use 1.17.1 --global, add my global env to PATH
3. Run fvm.bat flutter run
4. The project still runs in 1.17.1, not my global SDK version
   My procedure is below, I also post my question in [github](https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm/issues/198), I have tried a lot of methods but none worked. Does anyone have the same problem?
   [image: my procedure]

Comment: Don't paste screen shots.

Comment: Thanks for your notice. Is there any mistake? but why? Please let me know.

Comment: I'm mostly refusing to look at screenshots that could have been text, until they get reposted as text.

Answer (score 0):

Use fvm library

```
fvm: ^1.3.7
```

full documentation

[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/fvm)